# Determine table field(s) where IS_IDENTITY AND/OR IN_PRIMARY_KEY are checked?

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to determine the table column which has been identified as (or part there of) the primary key for a given table name.

I have been playing around with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and the data within it, but nothing seems to relate to these table columns.

Have also been browsing around this website:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933201%28v=sql.80%29.aspx
```

but without much luck so far.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found what I was looking for [here](http://coding-in.net/445/)